Using MySQL 'utf8mb4' but getting "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"
I have a project created in Laravel v10.48.20 and I'm using Laravel Nova v4.34.3 to show records.
I recently added some records with some German characters, and now the Nova resource is throwing this error every time:
Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

From the start of the project, I've had these settings in my config/database.php file:
'mysql' => [
    'driver'         => 'mysql',
    // ...other settings...
    'charset'        => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation'      => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    // ...other settings...
],

These UTF-8 chars shouldn't be causing this issue with the DB settings like this.
I ran this query to check our table to see if any values were incorrectly encoded and no results came up:
SELECT name FROM offers WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(name) != CHAR_LENGTH(CONVERT(name USING utf8mb4));

The PHP settings have default_charset = "UTF-8".
This is my Nova field:
Text::make('Name')
    ->sortable()
    ->help('The name of the offer.'),

What could be causing this issue?

Could be a Duplicate, but I suggest you start by reading this Q&Answers

I also encountered this error. You must remove these characters from your data; otherwise, this issue will persist. In my case, these columns with data related to AES_ENCRYPT caused this error.

In your code, some characters will not be suiteable with utf8 format.

Let's see SELECT name, HEX(name) ... for a row that is having trouble.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

@RiggsFolly definitely not a duplicate. Already have all the settings accounted for that they mention in that post.

@FaizanAli not storing those chars is not an option as we must support multilingual text. There is no encryption on the table or the column.

@RickJames I checked the hex encoding and when it decodes it looks fine. It is only when Laravel tries to return the response thru JsonResponse.php that is runs into this error. The problem only shows up when I save the word für to the DB and try to view it again in Laravel Nova.

@eComEvo - Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE so we can see what character set it inherited.  Also what does the HEX say?
